# check if font awesome exists before enqueueing to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, font-awesome

I'm trying to enqueue font awesome only if haven't been enqueued before.

This is my code:

```
function stylesheet_installed($array_css)
{
    global $wp_styles;

    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) 
    {
        foreach ($array_css as $css)
        {
            if (false !== strpos( $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src, $css ))
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

This function seems to be ok.

```
function add_scripts(){
    $font_awesome = array('font-awesome', 'fontawesome');
    if (stylesheet_installed($font_awesome) === 0)
    {
         // ALWAYS ENQUEUE FONT-AWESOME, NO MATTER THE CONDITION ABOVE
         wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'); 
    }    
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

However, something is wrong because font-awesome always is enqueued.

I'm stuck with this, any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by adding a low priority to `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' )` so that other plugins enqueue their styles first and the helper function `stylesheet_installed($array_css)` returns the desired value. Now the function returns 1 if font-awesome has been installed before, 0 if not. Before adding the priority always returned 0. Hope this helps others!!!

Comment: Hi, It would be helpful to others if you would create a new answer with the full code of your solution, and mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @harvey, I just added priority to the action: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts', 999 );` to call the `stylesheet_installed` function after font awesome is added/installed.

Answer (score 4):

A quick Google search turned up this function in the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is).

```
if (!wp_style_is( 'fontawesome', 'enqueued' )) {
    wp_register_style( 'fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css', false, '4.6.1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' );
}
```

Comment: What if font-awesome has been registered as xxx-fontawesome? For example I have this: llorix-one-lite-fontawesome-css and 2 other more installed! That's the purpose of the helper function above, check all the names. I will give this solution a try and will accept the answer if it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I use to do this way to implement fonts (and custom css) in my themes :

```
function custom_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css', false, '4.6.1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_styles' );
```

You can use this to add google fonts or any css you need.

Comment: Thank you, I don't want to do that if font-awesome was installed before, that's why I'm using the stylesheet_installed helper function. If the functions returns 1 your code (or mine) shoudn't be executed but it does.

Comment: You can add this line before registering the style : wp_deregister_style('fontawesome'); to be sure you'll use Your file.

Comment: I only want to know if font awesome is registered and the function I created do this job, but for any reason wp_enwueue skips the if condition (stylesheet_installed($font_awesome) === 0) and always enqueue the css, I think it must be a syntax (or semantic) error there but I can't find it...